# While adding data to a dictionary that holds list as it's value, all my previous keys get updated with the latest value of the list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
allWords = {}
groupIterate = []

for j in range(0,30):
    group = columnsList[j]
    groupIterate.clear()
    for i in range(30):
        word = maal[group][i]
        url = f'https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/{word}'
        groupIterate.append(url)
    allWords[group] = groupIterate
```

All the keys in "allWords" get updated by the latest value of the list "groupIterate". However, I don't want to overwrite but simply add new keys with the respective "groupIterate" list in that iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using only one `groupIterate` instance, that you set as value of each key, you may not `clear` it, but build a new one at each iteratinon

```
for j in range(0, 30):
    group = columnsList[j]
    groupIterate = []
    for i in range(30):
        word = maal[group][i]
        url = f'https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/{word}'
        groupIterate.append(url)
    allWords[group] = groupIterate
```

Or use a list comprehension

```
for j in range(0, 30):
    group = columnsList[j]
    allWords[group] = [f'https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/{maal[group][i]}' for i in range(30)]
```